# Create a custom UISearchDisplayController programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I was able to create an app using Storyboard - it has a navigation controller containing a table view controller with a search display controller and worked as expected.

I then decided to customize it by adding a `UIButtonBarSystemItemSearch` (magnifying glass) to the navigator bar so that when touched it would display the search bar over the navigator bar, just like `setDisplaysSearchBarInNavigationBar` does.  To do this I removed the `UISearchDisplayController` from the storyboard and added it programmatically as shown in the code below.  The `btnSearchClicked` function is called when the magnifying glass is touched, so the button is hooked up right.

My project is very similar to the Apple example project "[AdvancedTableSearch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AdvancedTableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html)" but without the scope bar.

```
- (IBAction) btnSearchClicked:(id)sender
{
  //Set up search bar
  UISearchBar *mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
  [mySearchBar setDelegate:self];
  [mySearchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:NO];

  // Set up search display controller
  UISearchDisplayController *mySearchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:mySearchBar contentsController:self];
  mySearchController.delegate = self;
  mySearchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
  mySearchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
  //mySearchController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
  mySearchController.navigationItem.titleView.opaque = NO;
  [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar];
}
```

I am having two problems with this approach. **The most important one is that even though I set the delegate properties, when I type into the search bar none of my delegate functions are called (specifically `shouldReloadTableForSearchString`)**.

The second problem is that the cancel button doesn't display despite calling the `setShowsCancelButton` method.

I've been learning iOS for the last year and reading everything I can find on SO, but can't figure this one out.  This is my last resort and I will fall back to the old storyboard approach with standard search bar if I must.  The reason I like this other approach is that I have a very long list of contacts (~5000) and don't want to have to scroll to the top to get the search bar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696260/creating-a-uisearchdisplaycontroller-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not adding the right searchDisplayController? you added self.searchDisplayController but inited a mySearchController. Try putting the last line as:
  [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:mySearchController.searchBar];